# Facing issue while installing Data bricks CLI. Not able to enter Token value at command prompt

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to install Data bricks CLI. At command prompt, I entered command Data bricks configure --token and provided Data bricks Host URL. After entering both values, it's asking value of Token. I have generated token value but it's not allowing me to enter...copy paste option is also not working so I am not able to install Data bricks CLI. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: what OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Yes Alex, I am using Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent versions of the Databricks CLI it doesn't show the pasted text because the value of token is a sensitive value. So just paste text into terminal using the standard shortcut (like described in this article), or via terminal menu (you should have `Paste` in the `Edit` menu), and press ENTER.

Comment: Hi Alex......Thanks a lot for your help....my issue got resolved. Installed databricks cli successfully.